# jquery Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal break statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, break

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal break statement

This is the warning i got when i try to break of the loop. What I want to do break of the loop when the condition is meet.In the example code I have two active class where I want to break out of the loop completely when the first active class is encountered.

```
<ul>
    <li id="foo1" class="bar">1</li>
    <li id="foo2" class="bar">2</li>
    <li id="foo3" class="bar">3</li>
    <li id="foo4" class="bar">4</li>
    <li id="foo5" class="active">5</li>
    <li id="foo6" class="bar">6</li>
    <li id="foo7" class="bar">7</li>
    <li id="foo8" class="active">8</li>
</ul>
```

js

```
$(function(){
    function setup(){
        var x,y,z;
         $("ul li").each(function(){
             //console.log($(this)[0].className);
             if($(this)[0].className === 'active'){
                 x = $(this)[0].className;
                 y = $(this)[0].tagName;
                 z = $(this)[0].id;
                 break;
             } 
         });
        var return_values = {
            class : x,
            tag : y,
            id : z
        }
        return(return_values);
    }
    var data = setup();
    console.log(data.class,data.tag,data.id);
});
```

JSFIDDLE [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5avxmeto/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To exit the anonymous function in the `each()` use `return false`. Also note that using a DOMElement to create a jQuery object to then access properties of the DOMElement is entirely redundant. Try this:

```
$("ul li").each(function() {
    if (this.className === 'active') {
        x = this.className;
        y = this.tagName;
        z = this.id;
        return false;
    } 
});
```

Also note that your code is effectively only ever selecting the first `.active` element, therefore the loop is redundant. You can select that element directly and retrieve the necessary properties from it. Try this:

```
const $li = $('ul li.active:first');
let x = $li.prop('className');
let y = $li[0].tagName;
let z - $li.prop('id');
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I thought return will exit the whole function, my bad I didn't try that.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. For reference, `return` only applies to the scope of the function which contains it.